# Relocating items in a list

Tags: c#, winforms, list

How can I make two items exchange their positions in a List<T>? For example, item 3 moves to position 1 and item 1 goes to position 3 in a list with five items. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just save one of the items in a variable before you overwrite it:

```
var temp = list[1];
list[1] = list[3];
list[3] = temp;
```